# Get all full visible objects on lListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView, which contains more elements then I can display at one time.Now I want to get Index off all Elements, which are full visible ( -> excluding those that are only partially visible).
At this moment I use `getFirstVisiblePosition()` & `getLastVisiblePosition()` into an `for-loop` to iterate them, but these method is not accurate as I want to.

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A ListView keeps its rows organized in a top-down list, which you can access with `getChildAt()`. So what you want is quite simple. Let's get the first and last Views, then check if they are *completely* visible or not:

```
// getTop() and getBottom() are relative to the ListView, 
//   so if getTop() is negative, it is not fully visible
int first = 0;
if(listView.getChildAt(first).getTop() < 0)
    first++;

int last = listView.getChildCount() - 1;
if(listView.getChildAt(last).getBottom() > listView.getHeight())
    last--;

// Now loop through your rows
for( ; first <= last; first++) {
    // Do something
    View row = listView.getChildAt(first);
}
```

---

**Addition**

> Now I want to get Index off all Elements, which are full visible

I'm not certain what that sentence means. If the code above isn't the index you wanted you can use:

```
int first = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
if(listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() < 0)
    first++;
```

To have an index that is relative to your adapter (i.e. `adapter.getItem(first)`.)

Comment: listView.getChildAt(index).getTop() trick work for me..thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do this is I would extend whatever view your are passing in `getView` of the `ListView` adapter and override the methods `onAttachedToWindow` and `onDetachedToWindow` to keep track of the indexes that are visible.

Answer (score 1):

Try onScrollListner and you can able to use getFirstVisiblePosition and getLastVisiblePosition.

This [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130389/how-to-get-items-currently-displayed-in-adapterview/13134100#13134100) link, it contain similar type of problem. I suppose you got your answer there..,.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but this problem is exactly what I had, it gives me not the index of ListEntry what is fully visible, it returns all Items on Screen...

Answer (score -1):

The above code is somewhat correct. If you need to find the completely visible location of view use below code

```
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState)  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = null;

    if (scrollState == 0) {
        int first =0;
        if (view.getChildAt(first).getTop() < 0)
            first++;
        int last = list.getChildCount() - 1;
        if (list.getChildAt(last).getBottom() > list
                .getHeight())
            last--;
        // Now loop through your rows
        for ( ; first <= last; first++) {
            // Do something

            View row = view.getChildAt(first);
            // postion for your row............ 
            int i=list.getPositionForView(row);
        }
    }
        // set the margin.
}
```