# Check when the first item of gridview is fully shown

Tags: java, android, gridview

I want to do something when first item of grid view is shown, and currently I'm doing this to achieve this.

```
if(((GridView)v).getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0)
{
    ...
    ...
}
```

But it runs when 1st item is slightly visible, but I want to run it when it is fully shown. Is it possible to achieve this by some mean. This code is inside touch event of gridview.

```
gridView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        private float mInitialY;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // 
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mInitialY = event.getY();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:


            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                final float y = event.getY();
                final float yDiff = y - mInitialY;
                if (yDiff > 0.0) {
                    //SCROLL DOWN
                    if(((GridView)v).getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0)
                    {

                    }
                    break;
                } else if (yDiff < 0.0) {
                        // SCROLL UP
                    break;

                }
                break;
            }

            // Handle ListView touch events.
            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can't you do it in `getView()` of adapter when its called for the view for position 0?

Comment: Actually I want to check this when user touches the screen and move it down

Comment: @Yawar use it in on scroll method

Comment: Using onscroll, can detect that first item is fully shown?

Comment: Edited my answer so that you can know what exactly I am trying.

Comment: You may find your answer here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180571/get-all-full-visible-objects-on-llistview/13181412#13181412