# setText in CountDownTimer in ListView Adapter in Android?

Tags: android, countdowntimer, settext, listview-adapter

I am working in an Wedding App where I am maintaining a ListView of feeds.

The First element of my Feed Screen ListView is having a TIMER for the CURRENT DATE to the WEDDING DATE.

As I have taken the `TIMER` in a `ListView`, it getting hard to update the text of the `TextView` in `onTick()` method.

Wedding time is only visible in the first element of the list view.

```
_time = new CountDownTimer(WeddingTimeinMiliSec, 5000) {
                String showDate;
                long subtractvalue = 1000;

                Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    long diff = Day.getTimeInMillis() - currentTime.getTimeInMillis();
                    diff-=subtractvalue;
                    StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer("");
                    if (diff > DAY) {
                        //showDate = showDate+""+(diff / DAY)+("days ");
                        final long dif = diff;
                        if(holder!=null && holder._dayRespTextView!=null){
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    holder._dayRespTextView.setText(String.valueOf((dif / DAY)));
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        text.append(diff / DAY).append(" days ");
                        diff %= DAY;
                    }
                    if (diff > HOUR) {
                        //  showDate = showDate+""+(diff / HOUR)+("hours ");
                        final long dif = diff;
                        if(holder!=null && holder._hoursRespTextView!=null){
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    holder._hoursRespTextView.setText(String.valueOf((dif / HOUR)));
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        text.append(diff / HOUR).append(" hours ");
                        diff %= HOUR;
                    }
                    if (diff > MINUTE) {
                        //  showDate = showDate+""+(diff / MINUTE)+("minutes ");
                        final long dif = diff;
                        if(holder!=null && holder._minRespTextView!=null){
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    holder._minRespTextView.setText(String.valueOf((dif / MINUTE)));
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        text.append(diff / MINUTE).append(" minutes ");
                        diff %= MINUTE;
                    }
                    if (diff > SECOND) {
                        //  showDate = showDate+""+(diff / SECOND)+("seconds ");
                        final long dif = diff;
                        if(holder!=null && holder._secRespTextView!=null){
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    holder._secRespTextView.setText(String.valueOf((dif / SECOND)));
                                }
                            });                         
                        }

                        text.append(diff / SECOND).append(" seconds ");
                        diff %= SECOND;
                    }
                    /*_tvTime.setText(""+WeddingTime);*/    
                    showDate="";
                    subtractvalue+=1000;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                public void onFinish() {

                }
            }.start();
```

**This is my CountDownTimer code that I am using inside the CONSTRUCTOR of my ListView ADAPTER.**

How can I update the text of the TextViews in the ListView's first element on onTick event. Please suggest me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this..

```
/**
* ADDING HEADER LAYOUT TO THE LISTVIEW
*/

View headerView = ((LayoutInflater)PostScreen.this.getSystemService(PostScreen.this.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).
inflate(R.layout.header_layout, null, false);
textview = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.countdown_tv);


 _time = new CountDownTimer(WeddingTimeinMiliSec, 5000) {
String showDate;
long subtractvalue = 1000;

Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
long diff = Day.getTimeInMillis() - currentTime.getTimeInMillis();
diff-=subtractvalue;
StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer("");
if (diff > DAY) {
//showDate = showDate+""+(diff / DAY)+("days ");
final long dif = diff;
dayThread = String.valueOf((dif / DAY));
text.append(diff / DAY).append(" days ");
diff %= DAY;
}
if (diff > HOUR) {
final long dif = diff;
hoursThread = String.valueOf((dif / HOUR));
text.append(diff / HOUR).append(" hours ");
diff %= HOUR;
}
if (diff > MINUTE) {
final long dif = diff;
minThread = String.valueOf((dif / MINUTE));
text.append(diff / MINUTE).append(" minutes ");
diff %= MINUTE;
}
if (diff > SECOND) {
final long dif = diff;
secThread = String.valueOf((dif / SECOND));
text.append(diff / SECOND).append(" seconds ");
diff %= SECOND;
}
showDate="";
subtractvalue+=1000;

String dateText = "<font color="+countDown_TextColor+">"+dayThread+
" DIAS </font> <font color="+countDown_TextColor+">"+hoursThread+
" HOURAS </font><font color="+countDown_TextColor+">"+minThread+" MIN</font>" +
"<font color="+countDown_TextColor+">"+secThread+" MIN</font>";
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(dateText));
}

public void onFinish() {

}
}.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question.  I've never had to do this before and this answer is just a shot in the dark, but I think you would find some way forward by looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130389/how-to-get-items-currently-displayed-in-adapterview).

Basically, you need to keep track of which items are visible in your `ListView`.  Only update the `TextView`s in those visible views.  To track the visible items you will need to set the `ListView`'s `OnScrollListener`. Use ListView#getFirstVisiblePosition() and ListView#getLastVisiblePosition() to save the first/last positions and then do something with that information.  I would try sending them to the adapter and then do what you need to in your adapter's getView() when you are dealing with one of those positions.

Personally I might do something like having my adapter implement some interface that the `OnScrollListener` could use to get those positions to the adapter.  You may need more than one `CountDownTimer`, or you may need to find an alternate method of calculating the time remaining for each event.

---

**UPDATE**

The thing with the interfaces would probably suit your purposes better, but here is a proof of concept sample code that will help my point be understood.

This code displays a very simple list in which all even numbered items have a time display that is updated once per second.  I make no claims as to the efficiency of this solution, only that it performs the intended task:

---

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.selectivelistitemupdating;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView mListView;
    MyCountDownTimer mMyCountDownTimer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.listView );
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter( this );
        mListView.setAdapter( adapter );

        mMyCountDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer( 1000, 1000, adapter );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        mMyCountDownTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        mMyCountDownTimer.cancel();
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

---

MyCountDownTimer.java

```
package com.example.selectivelistitemupdating;

import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    BaseAdapter mAdapter;

    public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval, BaseAdapter adapter) {

        super( millisInFuture, countDownInterval );
        mAdapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        this.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick( long millisUntilFinished ) {

        // NO OP
    }

}
```

---

MyAdapter.java

```
package com.example.selectivelistitemupdating;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final int COUNT = 30;

    private Context context;
    private DateFormat dateFormat;

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
        dateFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem( int position ) {

        return "Item " + String.valueOf( position );
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId( int position ) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {

        if ( convertView == null ) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from( getContext() ).inflate( android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, parent, false );
        }

        TextView text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( android.R.id.text1 );
        TextView text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( android.R.id.text2 );

        text1.setText( getItem( position ) );
        text2.setText( getTimeString( position ) );

        return convertView;
    }

    private CharSequence getTimeString( int position ) {

        if ( position % 2 == 0 ) {

            return dateFormat.format( Calendar.getInstance().getTime() );
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private Context getContext() {

        return context;
    }
}
```

---

activity_main.xml

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```