# retrieve the index of the first and the last visible item in the ListView or GridView?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gridview

Is there a solution to retrieve the index of the first and the last visible items on the screen in a `GridView` or a `ListView`???

I searched in developer documentation but there was nothing, and i just found an interface [`AbsListView.OnScrollListener`] with method [`onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)`] that the second parameter give the first visible item that i want, but for last visible item there were nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom `ScrollListener` and `setOnScrollListener` to the listView.

Hope this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130389/how-to-get-items-currently-displayed-in-adapterview) helps.

Comment: Thanks. your link i think is the thing that i really want

Answer (score 2):

You can acces the last visible item on list or grid using ( firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount ) - 1.